# Folder Actions missing in High Sierra?

Tags: finder, folders, automation, folder-action

I've been using folder actions for years.  Ever since upgrading to High Sierra, my folder actions still work but the ability to add new ones is missing.  When right clicking on a folder, there used to be options such as "Configure Folder Actions" and "Attach A Folder Action."  Now, at least on my Mac, those options are gone.

Where has this gone and how do I get it back?

I'm the only one who uses this Mac and I'm logged in as an Administrator.

Comment: isn't it in the "Services" contestual submenu (as "Folder Actions Setup...")?

Comment: Ah-HA!  It had been deselected in the Services prefs.  FIXED.  And now, it's back.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gio Valerio led me to the answer in his comment above.  Somehow, Folder Actions had been deselected in the Services preferences, thus they weren't showing up as an option.  By selecting it there, in Services Preferences, the option for folder actions shows up again in the menu when I right-click on a folder.  Problem solved.  Thanks Gio!